# Selecting Rows based on multiple values in column

Tags: sql-server, select

I have two tables(T1,T2).Below are sample records from these two tables.

```
T1
 --
    RNO    NAME
    ---   ------ 
    1      NAME1
    2      Name3
    3      Name4

    T2
    ---
    RNO    NAMES
    ---    -----
    1      NAME1,Name5
    2      Name4
    3      Name2
```

I want to select records from T2 based on 'NAMES' column in T2 table which contains any one value of 'Name' column in T1 table.

### FOR Example

```
Sample Output

RNO   Names
---   -----
1     Name1,Name5
2     Name4
```

'Name2' should not come in output because it does not exists in T1 table.Please help.

Comment: Your table design is pretty awful. Storing delimited is a no win situation because it violates 1NF. Don't do this to yourself. If you fix your architecture the query becomes simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
select t1.* 
from t1 
where exists (select 1 
              from t2 
              where t1.NAME like '%' + t2.NAMES + '%');
```

Comment: Selecting records from T2.so we have to change that query?

Comment: select t2.* 
from table t2  
where exists (select 1 
              from table t1 
              where t1.NAME like '%' + t2.NAMES + '%');

Comment: @Ram. . . Yes you will need to change table name.

Answer (score 0):

is this useful.?

```
SELECT * FROM T2
Inner join T1
 ON (
       (t2.Name=t1.Name)
          OR
       (t2.Name LIKE'%'+t1.Name+',%')
          OR
       (t2.Name LIKE'%,'+t1.Name+'%')
          OR
       (t2.Name LIKE'%,'+t1.Name+',%')
   )
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b4641/1